# Function to initialize two dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a c program in which I want to initialize a 2 dimensional array.
So I made this function :

```
void initLayer(int **layer, int *dimensions) {
    printf("initLayer\n");
    layer = malloc(sizeof(int*) * dimensions[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++) {
        layer[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * dimensions[1]);
    }
}
```

When I use this function there is no problem, but when I try to read the 2D array later I always get a segmentation fault.
I think it may be because the initialization made in the function are not saved when its finished.
Do you know how I could correct my function ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Indeed. No value is returned. `layer` is just a local vaiable (on the stack). Pass a pointer to `layer` and assign to that (to `*layer`). Use a debugger. It will show you.

Comment: You have to remember that in C all arguments are passed *by value*, meaning they are copied and inside the function the arguments are only copies. Modifying a copy (like assigning to e.g. `layer`) will not change the original.

Comment: In C, _initialize_ has a special meaning.  `int a[2][3] = { {1,2,3},{4,5,6}};` is an _initialization_ - which happens at object  defintion - not later.  What you want here is _assignment_.

Comment: "when I try to read the 2D array later I always get a segmentation fault." --> post that code.

Comment: `int **´ is **not** a 2D array. A pointer is not an array.

Comment: @chux: There is no need to be so rigid about language. The C standard itself includes assignment before use as initialization. E.g., 6.3.2.1 2: “… uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use)”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To passing pointer to function you need one more pointer.
`int **matrix;` is an array of arrays, so to fill it you need to pass it as a pointer, which is `int ***layer`. but it is weird.
also for changing data by pointer you need to add a star `*` before it. `*layer = ...`

```
#include <stdlib.h>


void initLayer(int ***layer, int *dimensions)
{
    *layer = malloc(sizeof(int *) * dimensions[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++)
    {
        *(*layer + i) = malloc(sizeof(int) * dimensions[1]);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int **matrix;
    int dimensions[2] = { 4, 6 };

    initLayer(&matrix, dimensions);

    // then do whatever you want
    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dimensions[1]; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = i * j;
        }
    }
}
```

as for me, better to use `typedef` to make code more readable:

```
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef int *  Array;
typedef int ** Matrix;


void initLayer(Matrix *layer, Array dimensions)
{
    *layer = malloc(sizeof(Array) * dimensions[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++)
    {
        (*layer)[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * dimensions[1]);
    }
}


int main()
{
    Matrix matrix;
    int dimensions[2] = { 4, 6 };

    initLayer(&matrix, dimensions);

    // then do whatever you want
    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dimensions[1]; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = i * j;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function, the `int **layer` pointer is copied. So, when you do `layer = malloc(...)` what actually happens is the function sets its local copy to the `malloc` result. What you want is to mutate the variable which you called the function with. You can do this by taking a `int ***layer` and passing in `&layer` when calling `initLayer`. Note that you must then use `*layer` instead of `layer` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have two approaches here:

- to pass a reference to the double pointer (`***int` in this case)
- or to return the allocated pointer as the result of your function:

---

in the first case:

```
void initLayer(int ***layer, int *dimensions) {
    printf("initLayer\n");
    *layer = malloc(sizeof(int*) * dimensions[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++) {
        layer[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * dimensions[1]);
    }
}
```

you pass a reference to a pointer, instead of passing the (uninitialized) pointer.  Remember, in C, all parameters are passed **by value**.  In this case, you can call your function as:

```
...
int**vector;
...
initLayer(&vector, dims);  /* you pass the address of your double pointer */
```

---

In the second case:

```
int** initLayer(int *dimensions) { 
    printf("initLayer\n");
    int **layer = malloc(sizeof(int*) * dimensions[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++) {
        layer[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * dimensions[1]);
    }
    return layer;
}
```

in this case, you call it as:

```
...
int**vector;
...
vector = initLayer(dims);  /* you receive your double pointer as a return value */
```